# Golang official MongoDB driver ObjectID weird behavior

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to use the official mongodb driver in golang and am seeing something unexpected.

If I have a struct like

```
type User struct {
    ID     primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Name   string             `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Email  string             `json:"email" bson:"email"`
}
```

I create a new instance of this with `Name` and `Email` but omit ID expecting that the DB will fill this with its value. Instead it uses all zeroes and so the second and so on inserts fail with

```
multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{E11000 duplicate key error collection: collection.name index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('000000000000000000000000') }}]}, {<nil>}]
```

If I use a `*primitive.ObjectID` I get the same class of error only on `null` instead of zeroes

```
multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{E11000 duplicate key error collection: collection.name index: _id_ dup key: { : null }}]}, {<nil>}]
```

It doesn't matter if I use the `omitempty` directive or not, same result.

If I omit the `ID` field entirely, it works, but then my struct doesn't have that data on it.

Is there a way to have the DB handle the ID? Or *MUST* I explicitly call the `NewObjectID()` function on the struct?

Comment: I don't think the server ever assigns values to `_id`, I think it's always the client (or client driver) responsible for generating them.

Comment: If thats the case then why does the driver not set a value when it sees a "null" or "0000000..." value being inserted? Are there cases when this is wanted? Why is it different than when that `_id` field isn't specified at all?

Answer (score 2):

> It doesn't matter if I use the omitempty directive or not, same result.

`omitempty` tag on `ID` should work. For example:

```
type User struct {
    ID     primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name   string             `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Email  string             `json:"email" bson:"email"`
}

collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), User{Name:"Foo", Email:"Baz"})
```

If you don't specify the `omitepmty` tag, then the behaviour that you observed is just [Go structs](https://gobyexample.com/structs) behaviour; whereby if any of struct fields are omitted it will be zero-valued. In this case because you have specified the field type to be [primitive.ObjectID](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive?tab=doc#ObjectID), `ObjectId('000000000000000000000000')` is the zero value.

This is the reason why you need to generate a value first before inserting, i.e.:

```
collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), 
                     User{ ID: primitive.NewObjectID(), 
                           Name: "Foo", 
                           Email: "Bar"})
```

> Is there a way to have the DB handle the ID?

Technically, it's the MongoDB driver that automatically generates the [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) if it's not supplied before sending to server.

You can try to use [bson.M](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson?tab=doc#M) instead of a struct when inserting to leave out the `_id` field, i.e.

```
collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), 
                     bson.M{"name":"Foo", "email":"Bar"})
```

Code snippet above is written using [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) v1.3.x

Comment: `omitempty` doesn't fix it. It still uses the zero/nil values. This is noted in the original post.

Comment: Which version of mongodb-go-driver are you using ? Also code snippet on the struct and also how you insert ?

Answer (score 0):

The `omitempty` struct tag should work:

```
type User struct {
    ID     primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name   string             `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Email  string             `json:"email" bson:"email"`
}
```

The `primitive.ObjectID` type implements the `bsoncodec.Zeroer` interface, so it should be omitted from the document if it's the empty object ID (all 0's) and the driver will generate a new one for you. Can you try this and post the output?

Comment: `omitempty` doesn't fix it. It still uses the zero/nil values. This is noted in the original post.

Comment: Can you share the code with `omitempty` added? I added `omitempty` to your struct definition and the driver generated an Object ID for the document as expected. I'm testing using v1.3.0 of the driver.

Answer (score 0):

While it might not be **The** solution, you should check that

- `omitempty` is written **WITHOUT SPACES**.

```golang
ID primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
```

and not

```golang
ID primitive.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id, omitempty"`
```

I swore a lot about this!

- If that fails, breakpoint inside `primitive.ObjectID.IsZero` to make sure that it is treated as zero. Preferebly, use `primitive.NilObjectID`.

Their code (objectId.go) goes:

```golang
func (id ObjectID) IsZero() bool {
    return id == NilObjectID
}
```

- In the bson code (struct_codec.go) I found

```golang
if cz, ok := encoder.(CodecZeroer); ok {
   zero = cz.IsTypeZero(rv.Interface())
} else if rv.Kind() == reflect.Interface {
// isZero will not treat an interface rv as an interface, so we need to check for the
// zero interface separately.
   zero = rv.IsNil()
} else {
   zero = isZero(rv, sc.EncodeOmitDefaultStruct || ec.omitZeroStruct)
}
if desc.omitEmpty && zero {
   continue
}
```

while the `omitempty` field is determined by parsing reflections

```golang
if useJSONStructTags {
   stags, err = JSONFallbackStructTagParser.ParseStructTags(sf)
} else {
   stags, err = sc.parser.ParseStructTags(sf)
}
...
description.omitEmpty = stags.OmitEmpty
```

Just check that stags.omitEmpty is `true`

I hope that helps.